# Is there R online editor with Plot and Save options?

Tags: r, editor

I'm looking for R online editor.
I need run basic calculation line-by-line and plot results on screen and save graphs into files (for example, .pdf or .jpg). 
I have found [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online) but I can't find how to work with plotting. I have tried

```
getwd()
hist(rnorm(100))
# Result...
# executed in 1.05 second(s)
```

**Question.** Is there R online editor with plot and save options?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R-Fiddle seems to plot what you are asking, and has a save function:
http://www.r-fiddle.org/

-Patrice

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have an online version of rstudio, which is awesome and exactly same with the desktop version of rstudio environment.

- Sign Up and login to https://rstudio.cloud/
- In the "New Project" drop-down, click on "New Project from Git
  Repo", then click on "import the repo"